# How to autowire Spring Beans into Lamba code?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, autowired

I'm setting up a spring-security saml 2.0 blueprint for my company.

I'm following the Howtos of [Ulises Bocchio](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.github.ulisesbocchio/spring-boot-security-saml-sample/1.0/source-code/com/ulisesbocchio/security/saml/config/SAMLConfig.java). Everything is fine so far - the sample authentication process works fine.

To follow the security guideline of our company, I have to make the SAMLConfig.java file configurable. My first thought was to autowire a component that loads the configuration from "somewhere"; like the following.

```
/**
* @author Ulises Bocchio
*/
@AutoConfigureBefore(WebSecurityConfig.class)
@Configuration
public class SAMLConfig {
  protected Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

  @Autowired
  private SAMLUserDetailsServiceImpl samlUserDetailsServiceImpl;


  @Autowired
  private SAMLProperties samlProperties;

  @Bean
  public SAMLAuthenticationProvider samlAuthenticationProvider() {
    final SAMLAuthenticationProvider provider = new SAMLAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setUserDetails(this.samlUserDetailsServiceImpl);
    provider.setForcePrincipalAsString(false);
    return provider;
  }
```

This won't work, because the SAMLProperties object is null. I'm not sure but is it possible, that spring security is initiated before other (application) components?

How can I achieve a dynamic configuration of [Ulises Bocchio's](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.github.ulisesbocchio/spring-boot-security-saml-sample/1.0/source-code/com/ulisesbocchio/security/saml/config/SAMLConfig.java) SAMLConfig.java file?

Comment: It looks as though you are using the old version of Spring Security SAML which depends on OpenSAML 2 and is no longer maintained. I'd update to the latest SAML support which uses OpenSAML 3 which is still maintained https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-saml2login It also works with Boot and supports externalizing your configuration easier.

Comment: Thanks for the info. That wasn't the cause, but I will update the libraries soon.

Answer (score 2):

I was hinted by a colleague to the following **INFO**-log-line:

```
@Bean method SAMLConfig.idpMetadataLoader is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.
```

My adapted version of the idpMetadataLoader method by Ulises Bocchio:

```
@Bean
BeanFactoryPostProcessor idpMetadataLoader(StaticBasicParserPool parserPool) {
return beanFactory -> {
  try {
    final Resource idpResource = new UrlResource(this.samlProperties.getIdpMetadataUrl());
    final String alias = this.samlProperties.getKeystoreAlias();
    final Timer refreshTimer = new Timer(true);

    final ResourceBackedMetadataProvider delegate =
        new ResourceBackedMetadataProvider(refreshTimer, new SpringResourceWrapperOpenSAMLResource(idpResource));
    delegate.setParserPool(parserPool);
    final ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata = this.extendedMetadata().clone();
    final ExtendedMetadataDelegate provider = new ExtendedMetadataDelegate(delegate, extendedMetadata);
    provider.setMetadataTrustCheck(true);
    provider.setMetadataRequireSignature(false);
    extendedMetadata.setAlias(alias);
    beanFactory.registerSingleton(alias, provider);
  } catch (final Exception e) {
    this.log.error("Error while confiure SAML", e);
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
 };
```

}

The point is, that the lambda code is translated in static code - so non-static class members can't be accessed. Quite simple solution was to deliver the Configuration as a method parameter.

```
  @Bean
  BeanFactoryPostProcessor idpMetadataLoader(SAMLConfigFile properties, StaticBasicParserPool parserPool) {
    return beanFactory -> {
  ...
  };
}
```